# Displaying Marker in QT QML Map

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to add marker in QT QML Map. This is the code that I use to add a marker in Map, but the marker is not displaying. Please do help! I'm a beginner in QT Programming. Sorry for my grammar. Thank you!

```
 Plugin {
    id: mapPlugin
    name: "osm" 
}

function addMarker(latitude, longitude)
{
var Component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:///views/marker.qml")
var Item = Component.createObject(window, { coordinate:
QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude) })
Map.addMapItem(Item)
 }

     Map {
         anchors.fill: parent
         plugin: mapPlugin
         center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.14, 14.15)
         zoomLevel: 14

         Component.onCompleted:
         {
         addMarker(59.14, 14.15)

         }
     }
```

Marker.qml

```
MapQuickItem
{
    id: marker
    anchorPoint.x: marker.width / 4
    anchorPoint.y: marker.height
    sourceItem: Image
{

  Image
    {
    id: icon
    source: "marker.png"
    sourceSize.width: 40
    sourceSize.height: 40
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the ids to refer to the components, for example if you had Map and run `Map.addMapItem(...)` to what Map would the item be added ?. On the other hand you have a bad habit: you use names of existing elements such as Item that is already a type, in this case change it to item to avoid confusion, considering the above the solution is:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtLocation 5.12
import QtPositioning 5.12

Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Plugin {
        id: mapPlugin
        name: "osm"
    }
    function addMarker(latitude, longitude)
    {
        var Component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:///views/marker.qml")
        var item = Component.createObject(window, {
                                              coordinate: QtPositioning.coordinate(latitude, longitude)
                                          })
        map.addMapItem(item)
    }
    Map {
        id: map
        anchors.fill: parent
        plugin: mapPlugin
        center: QtPositioning.coordinate(59.14, 14.15)
        zoomLevel: 14
        Component.onCompleted:addMarker(59.14, 14.15)
    }
}
```

On the other hand in marker you point out that an Image has as a child another Image, do you think it is correct?, it is not necessary so the corrected Marker code is:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.12

MapQuickItem{
    id: marker
    anchorPoint.x: marker.width / 4
    anchorPoint.y: marker.height
    sourceItem: Image{
        id: icon
        source: "marker.png"
        sourceSize.width: 40
        sourceSize.height: 40
    }
}
```

The complete example is in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55390091)